# Problem Assigning Static IP to CentOS Server

Tags: networking, centos, dhcp, static-ip

We have a sandbox server running CentOS that we run inside our office.  Our ISP has assigned us a block of 5 static IPs.  We now want to assign it a static IP.

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none # have also tried "static" here
HWADDR=00:13:72:*:*:*
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=173.*.*.161
GATEWAY=10.1.10.1
```

/etc/resolv.cnf is also set with the appropriate name servers from our ISP.

When I `ifdown eth0` then `ifup eth0` I get...

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

When I switch to DCHP, the machine has an IP assigned and there are no connection problems.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IP Address and gateway are in 2 totally different networks. So change your gateway or IP address to an address within the same network.

```
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=173.*.*.161    <--
GATEWAY=10.1.10.1     <--
```

Comment: yep.  you are correct.  not sure how I missed that one.  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You gateway address and your ip address must be on the same subnet. When the machine gets a DHCP assigned IP, what is the default gateway that gets assigned? Try using that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd pull down the networks and configure it manually so you can see what is what.

ifconfig the device manually (`ifconfig eth0 1.1.1.1 up` I *think* it was)

Try and ping a gateway, then add it manually `route add default gw 1.2.3.4` once you figure out exactly what it was. Everything should fall through from there.

Note, you may need the netmask in your `ifconfig` command.

Answer (score 0):

Further to PowerSp00n's answer regarding the wrong gateway (and you really do have 5 IP addresses) your subnet mask should be 255.255.255.248 (/29).

Comment: This isn't true, a block of IP addresses you get isn't the same as a subnet. An ISP can give you a few addresses out of an larger subnet.

Comment: he said "block of 5 IP addresses" -- the key term here is block, if it was a few IP addresses from different subnets (which is rare anyways) it wouldn't be called a block.

Comment: Like I said, a block of IP addresses isn't (always) the same as a subnet. A subnet is a block and a block can be a subnet. You can't assume he has a subnet and is using the wrong netmask.